# How to chain the commands 'date -d @xxxxxx' and 'find ./'?

Tags: shell, find, date

I have directories whose names are timestamps, given in milliseconds since 1970-01-01:

```
1439715011728
1439793321429
1439879712214
.
.
```

And I need an output like:

```
1442039711    Sat Sep 12 08:35:11 CEST 2015
1442134211    Sun Sep 13 10:50:11 CEST 2015
1442212521    Mon Sep 14 08:35:21 CEST 2015
.
.
```

I can list all directories by command:

```
find ./ -type d | cut -c 3-12
```

But I cannot put the output to the next command: `date -d @xxxxxx` and manipulate the output.

How can I do this?

Comment: How do those timestamps translate to epoch? Because your numbers are too long... (That first one - is `Fri Oct  2 05:35:28 47592`)

Comment: @Sobrique Clearly milliseconds since the epoch.

Answer (score 10):

You are on the right track (for a simpler solution, running only 2 or 3 commands, see below). You should use `*` instead of `./` to get rid of the current directory¹ and this simplifies cutting of the milliseconds somewhat, then just pipe the result into GNU `parallel` or `xargs`²:

```
find * -type d | cut -c 1-10 | parallel date --date=@{} +%c
```

to get

```
Sat 12 Sep 2015 08:35:11 CEST
Sun 13 Sep 2015 10:50:11 CEST
Mon 14 Sep 2015 08:35:21 CEST
```

and to add the seconds offset before that as your example indicates:

```
find * -type d | cut -c 1-10 | parallel 'echo "{} "  $(date --date=@{} +%c)'
```

or:

```
find * -type d | cut -c 1-10 | xargs -I{} bash -c 'echo "{} "  $(date --date=@{} +%c)'
```

to get:

```
1442039711  Sat 12 Sep 2015 08:35:11 CEST
1442134211  Sun 13 Sep 2015 10:50:11 CEST
1442212521  Mon 14 Sep 2015 08:35:21 CEST
```

However it is simpler to do³:

```
find * -type d -printf "@%.10f\n" | date -f - +'%s  %c'
```

which gets you the same requested output once more.

The disadvantage of using `*` is that you are limited by your commandline for its expansion, the advantage however is that you get your directories sorted by timestamp value. If the number of directories is a problem use `-mindepth 1`, but lose the ordering:

```
find ./ -mindepth 1 -type d -printf "@%.10f\n" | date -f - +'%s  %c'
```

and insert `sort` if needed:

```
find ./ -mindepth 1 -type d -printf "@%.10f\n" | sort | date -f - +'%s  %c'
```

¹ <sub>This assumes there are no nested subdirectories, as seems to be the case from your example. You can also use `./ -mindepth 1` instead of `*`</sub>
²<sub>You can replace `parallel` with `xargs -I{}` here as @hobbs and @don_crissti suggested, it just more verbose.</sub>
³<sub>based on Gilles' answer to use `date`s file reading capabilities</sub>

Comment: Or `xargs` if you don't have `parallel`, which many people probably don't.

Comment: @hobbs AFAIK `xargs` doesn't have the option to specify where the argument goes like `parallel` has with `{}`.

Comment: It does: `find ./ -type d | cut -c 3-12 | xargs -I{} date --d @{} +'%Y-%m-%d'`

Comment: @Anthon it does if you use the `-I` option.

Comment: @don_crissti thanks. But your `--d` option for `date` has a dash too many I think.

Comment: @Anthon, GNU long options can be abbreviated as long as they're not ambiguous.  `--d` or `--da` would work with current versions of GNU `date`, but it could stop working the day `date` introduces a `--dalek` option (for dates in the Dalek calendar).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ok. And `--dalek` would give different results depending on them having rewritten time or not, would be useful for the Doctor.

Answer (score 10):

I'd avoid running several commands per file in a loop. Since you're already using GNUisms:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type d |
  awk '{t = substr($0, 3, 10); print t, strftime("%a %b %d %T %Z %Y", t)}'
```

Which just runs two commands. `strftime()` is GNU-specific, like `date -d`.

Comment: This doesn't cut the milliseconds of the directory names but displays the full 13 characters instead of the requested first 10

Comment: @Anthon, ah yes, missed that requirement. Should be OK now.

Answer (score 8):

You already have:

```
find ./ -type d | cut -c 3-12
```

which presumably gets you the timestamps in epoch format. Now add a while loop:

```
find ./ -type d | cut -c 3-12 | while read datestamp
do
    printf %s "$datestamp"
    date -d "@$datestamp"
done
```

Note though that in some shells, that syntax gets the while loop in a subshell, which means that if you try to set a variable there, it won't be visible once you've left the loop. To fix that, you need to turn things on their head slightly:

```
while read datestamp
do
    printf %s "$datestamp"
    date -d "@$datestamp"
done < <(find ./ -type d | cut -c 3-12)
```

which puts the `find` in the subshell, and keeps the while loop in the main shell. That syntax (AT&T `ksh`, `zsh` and `bash` specific) is only needed if you're looking to reuse a result from inside the loop, though.

Comment: regardless, saying that it is bash-specific isn't correct :)

Comment: Actually, as you had initially written it, `done <(find)` instead of `done < <(find)`, it was correct for `yash` (where `<(...)` is process redirection, not process substitution), so my edit was a bit cavalier as it could have been the shell you meant that for.

Answer (score 6):

If you have GNU date, it can convert dates read from an input file. You just need to massage the timestamps a little so that it can recognize them. The input syntax for a timestamp based on the Unix epoch is `@` followed by the number of seconds, which can contain a decimal point.

```
find ./ -type d ! -name '*[!0-9]*' |
sed -e 's~.*/~@~' -e 's~[0-9][0-9][0-9]$~.&~' |
date -f - +'%s  %c'
```

Comment: +1 for using `date`s file reading. This will give a `date: invalid date ‘@’` because of the translation of the current directory (`./`). And since you can throw away the milliseconds you can simplify the second `sed` edit to just drop the last 3 characters. Or remove all of that and use `find * -type d -printf "@%.10f" | date ...`

Answer (score 5):

I would do it perlishly - feed in a list of timestamps:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

while ( my $ts = <DATA> ) { 
   chomp ( $ts );
   my $t = Time::Piece->new();
   print $t->epoch, " ", $t,"\n";
}

__DATA__
1442039711  
1442134211  
1442212521
```

This outputs:

```
1442039711 Sat Sep 12 07:35:11 2015
1442134211 Sun Sep 13 09:50:11 2015
1442212521 Mon Sep 14 07:35:21 2015
```

If you want a specific output format, you can use `strftime` e.g.:

```
print $t->epoch, " ", $t->strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),"\n";
```

Which to turn this into a one liner in your pipe:

```
 perl -MTime::Piece -nle '$t=Time::Piece->new($_); print $t->epoch, "  ", $t, "\n";'
```

But I'd probably suggest instead looking at using the `File::Find` module and doing the whole thing in perl instead. If you give an example of your directory structure before cutting it, I'll give you an example. But it would be something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
use File::Find; 

sub print_timestamp_if_dir {
   #skip if 'current' item is not a directory. 
   next unless -d; 
   #extract timestamp (replicating your cut command - I think?)
   my ( $timestamp ) = m/.{3}(\d{9})/; #like cut -c 3-12;

   #parse date
   my $t = Time::Piece->new($timestamp);
   #print file full path, epoch time and formatted time; 
   print $File::Find::name, " ", $t->epoch, " ", $t->strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),"\n";
}

find ( \&print_timestamp_if_dir, "." );
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU Parallel:

```
find ./ -type d | cut -c 3-12 | parallel -k 'echo {} `date -d @{}`'
```

If you can accept \t instead of space:

```
find ./ -type d | cut -c 3-12 | parallel -k --tag date -d @{}
```

Comment: Note that `parallel` is written in `perl`. This seems overkill considering that `perl` has a `strftime()` operator. Like `perl -MPOSIX -lpe '$_.=strftime(" %c", localtime substr $_, 2, 10)'`

Comment: 1. It is shorter. 2. You do not need to learn Perl.

Comment: It's 27% shorter, but it's several orders of magnitude less efficient (about 800 times as slow in the test I made; consider it needs to spawn  a shell (your shell, not /bin/sh) and a date command for each line) and unfriendly to the system as it burdens all CPUs at once. And you still need to learn `parallel`. IMO, `parallel` is a great tool to parallelize CPU intensive tasks, but not really appropriate for this kind of task here.

Comment: There are plenty of contexts where efficiency is not a concern, so it's still an acceptable solution, but it's still worth mentioning the performance issue, especially when considering that _parallel_ usually rhymes with _high performance_ in people's mind.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh` and the [strftime](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fdatetime-Module) builtin:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
for d (*(/))
strftime '%s %a %b %d %T %Z %Y' $d
```

this assumes all your directory names in the current directory are actually epoch times.
Further filtering/processing is possible provided you clarify how those numbers in your example should be processed (they look more like epoch times corresponding to the birth dates of Princess Leia and Luke Skywalker...) e.g. recursively search for directory names that match at least 10 digits and calculate the date based on the first 10 digits:

```
setopt extendedglob
zmodload zsh/datetime
for d (**/[0-9](#c10,)(/))
strftime '%s %a %b %d %T %Z %Y' ${${d:t}:0:10}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally find command can be chained with any command using `exec` argument.

In your case, you can do like this:

```
find . -type d | cut -c 3-12 | while read line
do
       echo -n "${line}  "
       date -d $line
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Python (it's the most possibly slower solution)

```
for i in $(ls -A); do echo $i | xargs python -c "from sys import argv;from time import strftime;from datetime import datetime;print datetime.fromtimestamp(float(argv[1][:-3])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),'---',argv[1]"; done
```

gives:

```
2015-08-30 08:48:59 --- 1440917339340
2015-08-31 08:00:22 --- 1441000822458
2015-09-01 08:00:32 --- 1441087232437
2015-09-01 16:48:43 --- 1441118923773
2015-09-02 08:00:11 --- 1441173611869
2015-09-03 08:00:32 --- 1441260032393
2015-09-04 08:00:21 --- 1441346421651
```

Comment: Why not do it all in python? Rather than chaining a bunch of pipes?

Comment: It would make better sense. I agree.